# MsiSetProperty for REG_MULTI_SZ using custom action

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am looking for API to set REG_MULTI_SZ string as a MSI property, checked with MsiSetProperty in custom action, but it sets only few characters till first occurence of \0.

Is there any API that can be used to set multiString? or trick to set property using current API.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Too busy to answer. However, [Reg.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) might do the trick. You can also do it via [WMI / Scripts](http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/os/registry/scr_998.asp). And [a related list](http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/os/registry/default.asp). And certainly  using managed code or C++ as well. Don't have samples for you right now.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You are reading a REG_MULTI_SZ value from the registry and want to place it into an MSI property? Or take a value you are trying to placed into an MsiProperty and place it into a REG_MULTI_SZ registry value?